# How to get a default column value from MySQL 5.7 information_schema.columns with appropriate quoting?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I maintain Beekeeper Studio, an open source SQL GUI.

I have a problem with `information_schema.columns` in MySQL 5.7.

when running:

```sql
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = ?`
```

It returns the `COLUMN_DEFAULT`, but it doesn't seem to differentiate between variables (eg CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), and a string 'foo'.

[image: default string vs variable]

Is there a place I can get the 'real' default value with appropriate quoting?

What I expect:

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
`'foo'`

Comment: Check column's datatype and wrap default value with quotes if needed. But remember that sometimes there is an ambiguity (for example, when the datatype is ENUM or SET). PS. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is a function, not a variable.

Comment: The real default value is already in the column `DEFAULT_VALUE`, just like the real column_name is in the column `COLUMN_NAME`. Quoting might be needed when trying to do something with the values, but quoting is not (or never) a part of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no metadata in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA that can tell you this in MySQL 5.7. You just have to know that for a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is a special case.

It is treated as a special case in the code, so if you use SHOW CREATE TABLE, it outputs the literal string "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" instead of a quoted datetime value.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/sql/sql_show.cc#L1402-L1411